# CAML query on a SharePoint 2010 List?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, caml

Im the following code:

```
string xpathresultBTADSLMAX = "BT/Max Standard";

if (xpathresult2 == "BT ADSL Max")
{

//Creating the CAML query to perfomr the query on the list to find the required values
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

//try to find items in this list that matches the result of the XPATH query performed 
earlier
//in this case "BT/Standard"
string camlquery = @"<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Vendor_x0020_Product_x0020_Name'/>
<Value Type='Text'>" + xpathresultBTADSLMAX + @"</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>  
</Query>";

query.Query = camlquery;
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Fabric_x0020_Name'/><FieldRef  
Name='Defined_x0020_For/><FieldRef name='MPLS'/>"; //selecting only the required  
fields 
from the CAML query

SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(query);


//string fabricName = (string)item["Fabric_x0020_Name"]; commented out temporarily

//string definedFor = (string)item["Defined_x0020_For"]; commented out temporarily

string fabricName = (string)item["Fabric_x0020_Name"];
string definedFor = (string)item["Defined_x0020_For"];

AvailabilityCheckerResultsTwo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(fabricName, definedFor 
));

}
```

In the above code I am trying to display specific information from a list item that has a Vendor Produc Name of "BT/Max Standard". The values I want to display are currently "Fabric Name" and "Defined For".

I then want to be able to display them in a asp Place holder by adding a literal control but its simply not working. Is there something that I am doing wrong here? Please provide some suggestion on how to achieve this.

Many Thans in advance!

UPDATED!!!

So I have made some changes to the code, which basically fixed the issue mentioned earlier. I am now ablke to display the results of the CAML query in the asp place holder.

```
string xpathresultBTADSLMAX = "BT/Max Standard";

//Executing the correct query based on a if condition for BT ADSL
if (xpathresult2 == "BT ADSL Max")
{

//Creating the CAML query to perfomr the query on the list to find the required values
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

//try to find items in this list that matches the result of the XPATH query performed 
earlier
//in this case "BT/Standard"
string camlquery = @"<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Vendor_x0020_Product_x0020_Name'/>
<Value Type='Text'>" + xpathresultBTADSLMAX + @"</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>  
</Query>";

query.Query = camlquery;
//query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Fabric_x0020_Name'/><FieldRef 
Name='Defined_x0020_For'/><FieldRef name='MPLS'/>"; //selecting only the required 
fields from the CAML query, GIVES ERROR

SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(query);


//string fabricName = (string)item["Fabric_x0020_Name"]; commented out temporarily

//string definedFor = (string)item["Defined_x0020_For"];
//string feniedFor = (string)item["Defined_x0020_For"];



//AvailabilityCheckerResults3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(fabricName + " " + 
definedFor));

//AvailabilityCheckerResultsTwo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(fabricName)); 
commented out temporarily

//string fabricName = (string)listItemCollection["Fabric_x0020_Name"].ToString;

/*string fabricName = listItemCollection.ToString();

AvailabilityCheckerResultsTwo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(fabricName));*/



foreach (SPListItem item in listItemCollection)
{
try
{

string results56 = (string)item["Fabric_x0020_Name"] + " " + 
(string)item["Defined_x0020_For"] + " " + "<b>MPLS:</b> " + (string)item["MPLS"] + 
"<br/>" + "<br/>";
AvailabilityCheckerResultsTwo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(results56));
}
catch (Exception err)
{
AvailabilityCheckerResultsTwo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(err.ToString()));
}
}

}
```

However i now have another problem in that I am getting all reacords from the List, and this is not the intended outcome. Here is the output:

Alpaca 
A dirty ADSL product for: CCTV third-party remote access interactive models and web site testing
MPLS: No

Burnet 
Home user & SOHO product (<5 user site) Can support <5 VoIP connections with 2 concurrent calls. IPT package
MPLS: Yes

The CAML query should only be displaying results for "Alpaca". How can I get only the required item and not all items in the list? Its probably something Im doing wrong!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

never include **query** tag in syntax 
try this

```
 string camlquery = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Vendor_x0020_Product_x0020_Name'/>
                      <Value Type='Text'>" + xpathresultBTADSLMAX + @"</Value>
                      </Eq>
                     </Where>";
```

further details you can see this artical http://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/new-in-sharepoint-2010-caml-query/

hops its helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try again with this - Remove the enclosed query tags from your variable camlquery

Comment: The reason I use the <Query> tags is becasue I want the query to bring back the full results. Then I use (query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Fabric_x0020_Name'/><FieldRef  
Name='Defined_x0020_For/><FieldRef name='MPLS'/>";) in order to select specific values from the result set. The problem I have is that I not to sure how to get the results displayed in the asp control

Comment: Have you checked whether you are getting the data back?

Comment: Ok, I see you are calling AvailabilityCheckerResultsTwo for adding controls. Can you put code for that method as well? Additionally, I am not sure what is the intent of the screen besides display of above data. If it's only above data, then you can possibly use DataViewWebPart as well.

Comment: The asp placeholder is just a normal place holder that I added to the webpart like so: <asp:PlaceHolder ID="AvailabilityCheckerResultsTwo" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>. There is no method involved.

Comment: Use SPGridView. It should be fairly quick. Refer here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx

Comment: Additional you can also use .Net's Repeater control - http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/